# Is there a way to get child elements to inherit border-radius? CSS

Tags: css

Was just wondering...

Is there a way to get child elements to inherit the parent border-radius values in CSS?

Thanks

Comment: `border-radius: inherit` ?

Comment: overflow:hidden to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with `inherit`:

> The inherit CSS keyword causes the element for which it is specified to take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
  
}
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section><div>a</div></section>
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)